# How to get a regex to match only words with defined characters for usernames and not define unallowed characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a rule for usernames and anything out of those rules should not match a username. Usernames can contain these characters:

- Uppercase
- Lowercase
- Numbers
- Underscore (_)
- Dash (-)
- Spaces

These usernames are valid:

```
User1
user2
_user_3
5user-
user 6
USER 7
```

These are invalid:

```
user@8
9us(ser
us=er 10
*user 11
```

Because they have characters that were not defined as allowed. When I use this regex:

`[\-\_a-zA-Z0-9].*(?![\w,])`

It matches all of them.

Is there a way to match only what is defined rather than having to use `[^]` to exclude every single character that is not allowed? I rather not create a string in code containing every single unicode character that is not allowed because there are thousands of them.

Comment: You could define what you want to match and use achors `^[-\w]+(?: [-\w]+)*$` See https://regex101.com/r/bBBfjc/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex pattern like this: /^[-_a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/
what that means is:

"^" From the start 
"[-_a-zA-Z0-9\s]" Look for one of this characters 
"+" one or more times 
"$" until the end

so from the start to the end it would only accept what I put between "[]"

```js
const pattern = /^[\-\_a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/;
    const goods = ['User1',
          'user2',
          '_user_3',
          '5user-',
          'user 6',
          'USER 7']
    
    const bads = ['user@8',
          '9us(ser',
          'us=er 10',
          '*user 11']
        
    goods.forEach(good => console.log("Is '" + good + "' a valid username? : " + pattern.test(good)))
    
    bads.forEach(bad => console.log("Is '" + bad + "' a valid username? : " + pattern.test(bad)))
```

PD: check https://www.debuggex.com/ for a cheatsheet in regex

Comment: Could you add an explanation for the OP and future readers why your solution works?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just invert your set, and `test` if any characters outside the set are in the string?

```js
const pattern = /[^\-\_a-zA-Z0-9]/;
const good = "esqew";
const bad = "es@qew";

if (!pattern.test(good)) {
  // proceed as normal
} else {
  // username contains disallowed characters
}

console.log("Is '" + good + "' a valid username? : " + !pattern.test(good));
console.log("Is '" + bad + "' a valid username? : " + !pattern.test(bad));
```